# Make Yesod Enum instance to PathPiece

Tags: enums, yesod

In my Yesod web-application I have following data type, that use like Enum in my model:

```
data ImageType = U | P | G  
    deriving (Show, Read, Enum, Eq, Bounded)
derivePersistField "ImageType"
```

I want use `ImageType` as params on my routes

```
/plain/#ImageType  PlainR GET
```

So I make `ImageType` instance to `PathPiece`

```
imageTypeToText :: ImageType -> T.Text
imageTypeToText U = "U"
imageTypeToText P = "P"
imageTypeToText G = "G" 

instance PathPiece ImageType where
    toPathPiece = imageTypeToText
    fromPathPiece s = case (s == "U")  of
      False -> Nothing
      True -> Just $ U
```

the problem is that get the following error

> Foundation.hs:97:15:
>       Couldn't match type ‘ImageType -> Route App’
>                      with ‘Route (HandlerSite (WidgetT App IO))’
>       Expected type: WidgetT
>                        App IO ((ImageType -> Route App) -> [(Text, Text)] -> Text)
>         Actual type: WidgetT
>                        App
>                        IO
>                        (Route (HandlerSite (WidgetT App IO)) -> [(Text, Text)] -> Text)
>       In the first argument of ‘(>>=)’, namely ‘getUrlRenderParams’
>       In a stmt of a 'do' block:
>         (getUrlRenderParams
>
> > =
> >              (\ urender_a1tOQ
> >                 -> (asWidgetT GHC.Base.. toWidget)
> >                      (toHtml (\ u_a1tOR -> urender_a1tOQ u_a1tOR [] PlainR))))

the Foundation.hs code is

```
    $(widgetFile "default-layout") --Line 97
withUrlRenderer $(hamletFile "templates/default-layout-wrapper.hamlet")
```

Comment: This looks like you're missing an argument to `PlainR` in your default-layout-wrapper.hamlet file. Do you need to replace `PlainR` with `PlainR U` (or equivalent) somewhere?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman you are right sorry, I forgot a parameter in the menu in my default-layout